# Why the angular custom validator is called twice on initial page load and how to prevent it?

Tags: angular, angular-custom-validators

I have binded custom validator on checkbox and observed that custom validtaor is called twice on initial page load, this is causing issue because my validator is used to count the number of checkbox checked, since it is called twice, counter value is incorrect.

I added the console log in custom validator function and checked, it is called twice.

```
taskSelectionInJobValidation(formctrl:FormControl) {
if(formctrl.value == true){
  this.tasksInJobCount ++;
} else{
  this.tasksInJobCount --;
}
console.log(this.tasksInJobCount);
if (this.tasksInJobCount < 1) {
  return {
    valid : false
  }
}
return null;
```

}

Custom validtor function should be called once, it is called twice and I want to prevent this to call only once on page load.

Comment: change your custom validator. Make over all the form, and count the values checked

Answer (score 0):

Basically the validation is fired twice - once when loosing the focus of the input  when clicking the Update button (the input looses focus before the Update button click event is fired) and once for the validating all inputs in the PopUp editor after pressing the "update" button (this behavior cannot be prevented). In current case I would suggest to use the save event of the grid to display the confirmation message to the user or implement custom code to track which validation is fired - when loosing focus of the input or clicking the "update" button.

> Calling `enableProdMode()` before `bootstrap()` should fix it:

```
import {enableProdMode} from "angular2/core";

enableProdMode();
```

By default Angular2 runs in devMode where change detection always runs twice to check for model instabilities that indicate a bug in your application (which produces the error message Expression 'xxxx' was changed after it was checked)